# Best way to call function again in React

Tags: php, reactjs

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to use a function to fix an input of a date. Basically, if the date is missing, I am going to make it default to '9999-12-31' to make it easier for my PHP backend to insert it into a database. When saving a form, it calls the validateInputs function, which corrects the missing date and then calls the onSave function. If I do it like this:

```
    validateInputs: function(e) {
        if (!this.state.expire_date || this.state.expire_date == '') {
            this.setState({ expire_date: '9999-12-31' });
        }
        this.onSave(e);
    },
```

It will set the date in the field itself and fail to save.

But if I do this:

```
    validateInputs: function(e) {
        if (!this.state.expire_date || this.state.expire_date == '') {
            this.setState({ expire_date: '9999-12-31' });
            this.validateInputs(e);
        }
        this.onSave(e);
    },
```

it will save but I will get a console error saying maximum call stack has been exceeded. I know this probably has something to do with my understanding of how components are rendered and state is managed, but I'm not good enough with React to figure out more.

Comment: That happened because you called the same function in the same function. It caused in an infinite loop and caused _maximum call stack...._.

Comment: Please remove the PHP tag since this is a pure JS/React issue.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async operation. So, when you call the same function again state might not be updated immediately. So in your code it happens to cause ***maximum call stack has been exceeded*** as same function gets called again and again.

IMHO, you should use a callback function in the setState to call after state gets updated as:

```
validateInputs: function(e) {
    if (!this.state.expire_date || this.state.expire_date == '') {
        this.setState({ expire_date: '9999-12-31' }, ()=>{
            this.validateInputs(e); // <-----call it here again.
        });

    }
    this.onSave(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async, meaning the component state won't update immediately in the next line of code, you can only see the new state in the next render cycle, or in the callback as second argument of `setState`.

So you may want to update your function to something like this:

```js
validateInputs: function(e) {
    if (!this.state.expire_date || this.state.expire_date == '') {
        this.setState({ expire_date: '9999-12-31' }, () => {
            // NOTE: async code - e is nullified
            this.validateInputs(e);
        });
    } else {
        this.onSave(e);
    }
},
```

However, please note that [React event is pooled](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), which means you cannot access the values of event object in your asynchronous code